# Strange Mouse Issue

Tags: mouse, hdmi

About a few days ago, I installed elementary OS on my Lenovo IdeaPad 110 laptop. I also have this monitor, (all the labels are worn off, so I can't identify) which I link using an HDMI to VGA cable. The issue is that the mouse creates some sort of trail, with also cutting off some of the page, and also creating some slowdown, but only if it's connected with HDMI. Is this a problem with my cord? My monitor? My laptop?